# Remove Duplicate duplicate <li> tags in a <ul>

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have a series of html files in a folder. I'm looking to go through each html file and remove duplicate `<li>` tags. For Example:

```
<ul>
<li class="toctree-l1"><a class="reference internal" href="zone.html">zone</a></li>
<li class="toctree-l1"><a class="reference internal" href="zone.html">zone</a></li>
</ul>
```

to

```
<ul>
<li class="toctree-l1"><a class="reference internal" href="zone.html">zone</a></li>
</ul>
```

I need to open each file, compare the `<li>` tags between `<ul>` and `</ul>` and remove duplicates. 
I'm trying to accomplish this using python. I'm not sure how to parse the elements and make comparisons. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

I have this so far.

@thanks alecxe. This is my final code that worked:

```
import sys
import os
from os import path
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

directory_path = '..'
output_directory_path = '..'
files = [x for x in os.listdir(directory_path) if path.isfile(directory_path+os.sep+x)]

for fname in files:
    fout = fname.split(".")[0]
    #print fout
    seen = set()
    a = directory_path+"/"+fname
    #if != directory_path+"/"+fname
    if not a.endswith("_index.html"): continue
    with open(a) as f:
        #print f
        soup = BeautifulSoup(f)
        #print soup
        for li in soup.select('ul li.toctree-l1'):
            if li in seen:
                li.extract()  # remove tag if seen
            else:
                seen.add(li)
        #print soup
        fout =  output_directory_path + "/" +fout+".html"
        #print fout
        fp = open(fout ,'w')
        #print fp
        soup = soup.prettify(soup.original_encoding)
        #print soup
        fp.write(soup)
        fp.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea would be to maintain *a set of seen `li` tags* and [remove](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract) an `li` tag if was already seen:

```
for fname in files:
    seen = set()
    with open(fname) as f:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(f)
        for li in soup.select('ul li.toctree-l1'):
            if li in seen:
                li.extract()  # remove tag if seen
            else:
                seen.add(li)
```

Leaving the rest of the logic for you to implement.

Comment: @Ashwin please avoid posting large code snippets into comments. Edit the question and put the code there. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm getting the foll error:                                         for li in soup.select('ul li.toctree-l1'):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: @Ashwin please try updating beautifulsoup: `pip install --upgrade beautifulsoup4`.

Comment: @alexce Thanks. It's already the updated version. I get the foll message: Requirement already up-to-date: beautifulsoup4 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages.

Comment: @Ashwin do you import `BeautifulSoup` as `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`?

Comment: I have updated the question. Can you please tell me how to fix the IO error ?